# Get text drawn by ExtTextOut

Tags: c, winapi, text, printing, output

I'am trying to get the text outputing by `ExtTextOutW` function, and the first thing that i came up with is, that go and hook this function, for example by injecting dll in the target process. So from there i can get the `hdc`, text and flags. However, i have the application that calls this function many many times, so i don't want to hook and make checks for all the calls. Is there a way, i can get the text printed on form by `ExtTextOutW` without hooking it, maybe using the `hdc` where it outputs the data?

Comment: What are you trying to do that you think you need to hook ExtTextOutW?

Comment: @EricBrown basically i have a listbox with fields which is created withoud using Winapi, just plain gdi, and it is drawn using gdi, its made like a window with hwnd and a lot of 'labels', where the text is put using that function. I want to be able to get all values of that listbox, and then select them by emulating `SendMessage` with buttondown message maybe to this listbox window, with the coordinates of where the text is outputed.

Comment: Have you tried [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx) or [MS Active Accessibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

Hooking is the only way you can get the parameter data that is being passed to `ExtTextOutW()`. If you are only interested in data for a specific `HDC`, you will have to filter accordingly.  However, `HDC`s tend to be created dynamically when needed, so you likely cannot filter on the actual `HDC` value itself, as it will be different each time.  Fortunately, if the `HDC` belongs to a window (and it sounds like you want to intercept calls for a specific window), you can use [`WindowFromDC()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145201.aspx) to get the `HWND` of the `HDC` that is being drawn on, and then filter on that as needed.